# Can't Deploy App to my Windows Phone

Tags: windows, mobile, windows-phone, windows-10-universal

I'm developing an app using the Cordova tools for VS 2015 Enterprise. I would like to test my app on Windows Phone, but when I try to debug using the built in "device" option, I get these errors:
[image: Errors]

Does anyone know how to fix this? For reference, I'm using a Lumia 550, in developer mode, which is plugged in through USB to a computer running Windows 10 (with the latest version of VS and the Cordova tools). I looked in my services app, and IpOverUsbSvc is running already. I'm using the latest version of VS and my phone was updated to the latest version of WP10 today.

I have tried doing a hard reset on the phone, as well as using WPPT to deploy the app, both of which did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue for Insider Builds. Please see similar case [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9304af75-a544-4c08-9334-f807610878d1/cannot-deploy-uwp-app-to-win10m-14356-dep0001-unexpected-error-2147014836?forum=wpdevelop).

Please try rolling back to stable version (e.g. 10586).

You can use [Windows Device Recovery Tools](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq) to roll back.

> **Will this tool work on phones running Insider Preview builds?**
>
> Yes. When you use this tool on a phone that's running a preview build, it will reinstall the latest version of Windows approved for your phone by its manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you so so so much! I've struggled with this error for weeks and your solution finally fixed it. I never signed up for Insider Preview builds, so I didn't know I had that. But the Recovery Tool worked like a charm, even when the hard reset didn't fix it.